# How to read a text file and count how many lists it contains?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, list

I'm writing a program which is converting, sorting and generally doing automate tasks.

My problem is now: **I don't know how to count how many lists a text file contains.**

The Format in the text file is like this:

`["apple", "banana", "cherry"]`

`["apple", "banana", "cherry"]`

I tried already some options with `len()` but only get the number of letters.

Comment: Do you want the number of lists in the file, or the number of elements in each list? Can the file contain things that aren't valid representations of Python lists? And most importantly, **can you show us the code of what you've tried so far**?

Comment: an answer was helpful.. thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if each line contains a different list then you can count lines, by using simply

```
file = open("filename.txt", "r")
len(file.readlines())
```

otherwise if you want to read and store each list into a different list then you can do something like this

```
file  = open("input.txt", "r")
lists = []
for line in file.readlines():
  lst = line.replace("[", "").replace("]","").replace("\"","").replace("\n","").split(", ")
  lists.append(lst)
print(len(lists))
```